# Unexecuted validation using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to use the jQuery validation plugin to validate a login modal. This is what i have tried [so far](http://jsfiddle.net/sm29s4xe/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    handleSubmitForm();
});

function handleSubmitForm(){

$('#loginModal input.btnSubmitLogin').click(function(){

    $('#loginForm').validate(
            {
                rules : {
                    identification : {
                        required : true,
                        minlength : 5
                    },
                    loginPassword : {
                        required : true,
                        minlength : 5
                    }
                },
                messages : {
                    identification : {
                        required : "Please enter your email or your username",
                        minlength : "Your username must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                    loginPassword : {
                        required : "Please provide a password",
                        minlength : "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    }
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    var name = $(element).attr("name");
                    error.appendTo($("#" + name + "_validate"));
                },submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
        });


    });


}
</script>
```

I want to add the error messages below the text box; But on executing this code, nothing happens! Can you supply some examples to help me figure how put this together to get the following output:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Edit : Add the template where i make the references

```
<%@ include file="taglibs.jsp"%>
<html>
     <head>

     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>

     <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

     <link href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <!-- Fonts -->
     <link
         href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>"
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/animate.css"/>"
         rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/color/default.css"/>"
         rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- Boostrap JS -->

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/jquery.easing.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/jquery.scrollTo.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/wow.min.js"/>"></script>


<!-- Custom CSS -->

<link href="<c:url value="/customCSS/style1.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link href="<c:url value="/customCSS/style2.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/customJs/custom.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/customJs/jquery-1.11.1.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/customJs/dist/jquery.validate.js"/>"></script>
<!-- Kendo CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/kendo/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/kendo/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css"/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />" />
<!-- Kendo JS -->

<script src="<c:url value="/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/kendo/js/jquery.min.js" />"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Error 
[image]

Comment: Have you added `Jquery validate` plugin in your page.

Comment: @NeerajDubey Locks like that the problem is the reference to the plugin location. I am using bootstrap and kendo libraries for my pages. I updated the question by adding the part where i reference jquery validate. It is there an order that i should put that references?

Comment: Of Course the order of including js is correctly else you have got `unexpected function error`.

Comment: I added a picture with the error that i am getting now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have created example using `Jquery validate` for you ,please take a look.

```
$(function() {

// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        agree: "required"
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        agree: "Please accept our policy"
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});

 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/sm29s4xe/1/)